# How to get file extension when renaming file with cffile

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using a `cffile` tag to upload my file and resave it with a new name. My issue is that the file could be a few different formats and I don't know how to detect the file extension. I'm using the code below:

```
<cfset ui = createUUID()>
<cffile 
  action="upload" 
  accept="video/x-flv, video/mp4, video/x-msvideo"
  destination="e:\www2\uploads\#ui#.#cffile.ServerFileExt#" 
  nameconflict="makeunique" 
  filefield="form.file"
>
```

It's telling me that cffile is undefined.

Comment: The `CFFILE` variables are not populated until after the upload. So as scrittler said, upload first, then rename.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend uploading first, then renaming:

```
<cfset ui = createUUID()>
<cffile 
  action="upload" 
  accept="video/x-flv, video/mp4, video/x-msvideo" 
  destination="e:\www2\uploads\" 
  nameconflict="makeunique" 
  filefield="form.file"
/>
<cffile 
  action="rename" 
  source="e:\www2\uploads\#cffile.serverFileName#" 
  destination="e:\www2\uploads\#ui#.#cffile.serverFileExt#"
/>
```

Comment: In this scenario, how would you capture the new name for the database? CFFILE.clientFileName Get's you the orignial name, but using cffile.serverFileName just gives the name pre-rename.

Answer (score 0):

I found this awesome function created by [Ryan Stille](http://www.stillnetstudios.com/get-filename-before-calling-cffile/)

It should do everything you need

I used it to get the extension then I just created a file name with a UUID

```
<cffile action="upload" destination="file://upload_#createUUID()#.#fileExt#"  nameconflict="makeunique" result="#formField#">
```